# JQuery: Check form for errors

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to write a jquery(ajax) code that check some fields in the html form for validation before submit and also if any error occurs the message must display in the div with id response but it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form #response').hide(); //hide the response div in the html

  $('#create').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); //stop the form from submitting

    var valid = '';
    var required = ' is required';
    var name = $('form #fname').val();
    var email = $('form #email').val();
    var username $('form #username').val();
    var pword = $('form #password').val();

    if (name == '' || name.length <= 2) {
      valid = '<p>Your name ' + required + '</p>';
    }


    if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
      valid += '<p>Your email ' + required
    }

    if (username == '' || username.length <= 2) {
      valid += '<p>A username ' + required + '</p>';
    }

    if (pword == '') {
      valid += '<p>A username ' + required + '</p>';
    }

    if (valid != '') {
      $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
        .html('<strong>Please correct the errors below.</strong>' + valid).fadeIn('fast');
    }

  }); //click function
}); //ready function
```

```css
#response {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  color: #333;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#response p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.error {
  background: #FF9F9F url(img/alert.png) no-repeat 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="createForm" name="theForm" method="post" action="createUser.php">
  <legend><span class="icon"><img src="/registerUser/img/createIcon.png"></span> Create New User</legend>
  <p><span id="requiredfields">* required field.</span>
  </p>


  <!--<span id="errorMessage"> </span>-->
  <div id="response">
    <!--This will hold the message and the response from the server-->
  </div>

  <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name *" pattern="^[A-Za-z ]+$">
  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username *">
  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password *">
  <br>
  <br>

  <label for="roles">Roles:</label>
  <select id="role" name="roles">
    <option>Select Role</option>
    <option value="empty"></option>
    <option value="Reporter">Reporter</option>
    <option value="Lover">Lover</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="create" type="submit" name="createUser" value="Create User">

</form>
```

Comment: "it is not working" How? What is it supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: Yeah is not working, div shows without displaying the error message and my initial plan was to hide the div. Which means the div must fade in fast to show the message.

Comment: cant you just add required to the inputs -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: @Tasos - You can but can easily be bypassed. Same with client side script so it's best you have some server side validation as well.

Comment: @James111 It's not entirely useless. You do need server-side validation, but client-side validation can tell use user that he has made a mistake even before the data is sent off, which can often be beneficial.

Comment: well you just need to secure your form regardless if you are using required or not-- check the net on how to secure a form. using php is one option

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, and many other languages for that matter, `=` is an assignment operator. That means that

```
if(a = 3) { // blah blah blah
```

does not compare `a` to 3. Instead, it assigns the value of 3 to `a`, which is probably why your code isn't working. The comparison operator for equality is `==`, but it's better to use `===`, as it behaves more consistently with regard to weak comparisons. Your code should work if you replace the code in your `if` clauses.